# Test Kitchen with vsphere

Tags: chef-infra, vmware, vsphere, test-kitchen

I am getting following error when i try to run `kitchen test` :

```
Starting Kitchen (v1.3.1)
Cleaning up any prior instances of <default-centos-65>
Finished destroying <default-centos-65> (0m0.00s).
Testing <default-centos-65>
Creating <default-centos-65>...
Please see .kitchen/logs/default-centos-65.log for more details
------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Fog::Compute::Vsphere::NotFound
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

My .kitchen.yml file is :

```
driver:
  name: vsphere
  use_sudo: false
  hostname: <vsphere host name>
  privileged: true

driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: 11.4.4
  username: 'root'
  password: <password>
  authentication:
    vsphere_username: 'root'
    vsphere_password: <password>
    vsphere_server: <vsphere host name>
    vsphere_expected_pubkey_hash: <public hash>
  server_create:
    datacenter: <datacenter name>
    template_path: <template path>
  sudo: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.5
```

Can anybody please help me out

Comment: Hi Guys, I am able to resolve above issue, it was problem with `datacenter` name.
But now I am getting different error which is :
`Message: Failed to complete #create action: [NoPermission: Permission to perform this operation was denied.]`